# Getting server location where the particular website is hosted

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to build an application in java that takes domain name from user and look for the server location where it is hosted. and then display that specific location on google map..
 i am not getting any specific information related to that can anybody help me out and give some suggestion regarding that

Answer (score 1):

- Lookup server IP
- And determine server location using latest database from MaxMind see http://www.maxmind.com/app/java

Comment: ok. i am trying to dump the data in csv file for country in the msql database and then connect from that database and query for the respective ip address.. CAn u tell me how can i copy the data in the csv file of GeoIP Country CSV Text Files  in my mysql databse

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do:

1. Query the domains whois data and use the registrant address provided there.
   This really depends on if the address is public, so you might get an inaccurate address or the registrar's address (instead of the registrant).
2. Resolve the domain to an IP and Use GeoIP libraries to estimate it's approximate location. The accuracy might be on the city level but tha's as good as it probably gets.